# Controller cannot be found in java fx

Tags: java, javafx

I used Eclpse Luna and java 8  to create java fx Project. But when I try following code

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MainController">
   <fx:include fx:id="dialog" source="dialog.fxml"/>
   ...
</VBox>

public class MainController extends Controller {
    @FXML private Window dialog;
    @FXML private DialogController dialogController;
 }
```

it says that the Controller cannot be found

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers                    
Actually itried this example

Comment: Yes, but com.foo.MainController is sought. Just wanted to make sure the class is in package com.foo.

Comment: @JoopEggen means that you should add that line to your code.

Comment: I think Controller is in Built class which can be used instead of Initializable.https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm u can see that here

Comment: There is no builtin class Controller a controller does not need to derive from any base class

Comment: I guess @tomsontom is right, are you sure that what you have isn't a compile error regarding the `Controller` class, which does not exist (or isn't imported) ?

Comment: In the XML `fx:controller=...` specifies package&class that should be a Controller child.

Comment: Where do you see this specified - believe me this must not be!